# can't get white symbols for status bar

Tags: react-native

I have a dark navigation bar and want the status bar to have light icons, but i can't get it working. I've tried

```
export default function App() {
    const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

    return (
    <NavigationContainer>
            <StatusBar barStyle="light-content"/>

            <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{
        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: "#282d37",
        },
        headerTintColor: "#dfe9f5",
        headerTitleAlign: 'center'
      }}>
                <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} options={{ title: 'Login' }} />
            </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

but the icons are still dark. i am testing on an android device with Android 12

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the StatusBar from the Login screen:

```
function Login({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={[styles.container, { backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1' }]}>
      <StatusBar barStyle="light-content" />
      <Text>Dark Screen</Text>
      <Button
        title="Next screen"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Screen1')}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try change the background color accordingly when change barStyle, see this expo snack in action:

[React Native StatusBar Example](https://snack.expo.dev/@CatOverflow/89f1f9)

[image]

I think the [official documentation](http://reactnative.dev/docs/statusbar#statusbarstyle) does not make it clear, cause background does not change automatically when change barStyle of the StatusBar. only the colors of text and icon changed.